# Showing that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions with $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) \neq 0$, show that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$.

I consider that perhaps:

$$
\begin{align}
\\ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0+x) - f(0)}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}} = f'(0) \cdot \frac{1}{g'(0)} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}
\end{align}
$$

But, it seems like that's maybe not quite right. I'm not certain.

Insight?

Comment: [L'Hôpital's rule.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: No, that's right. You can move the limit inside the product and into the inverse for various reasons of continuity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've done it right?

Comment: You have to give a reason that you can move the limits into the inside, but it is the right argument. You might want to add the intermediate term: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}\frac{x}{g(x)}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you mean? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean by saying I have to give a reason that I can move the limits into the inside? Inside of the functions? I'm not clear what you mean.

Comment: Alex: Thomas is telling you that your proof is wrong. The limit can be split into the product of limits that you've written only under certain conditions; perhaps you should look at the theorem on when a limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits.

Comment: @JohnHughes Could have fooled me. It would seem that he was saying I'd done it right apart from stating why I can move the limits to some certain spot. I don't see what in particular is or isn't missing from what I've stated.

Comment: @JohnHughes Technically, I was saying there were reasons missing from the steps, and was *not* saying the proof was wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm confused. What am I missing? Also, I never intended for this to necessarily be a rigorous proof. That's why I didn't label it as a proof. Someone else labeled it as a proof. I don't mind adding some good rigorous reasoning to it, but primarily I want to know that my argument is correct (even if it makes a couple assumptions). My assumptions are correct though, aren't they?

Comment: @Thomas: I figure a proof with missing reasons is a wrong (or at least "incomplete") proof. But I grant that not everyone is so strict. (And I confess to have not always met this standard myself.) And I actually DID misread your "No, that's right" as "No, that's not right". :) Evidently my reading standards are lower than my proving standards.

Comment: @JohnHughes Wrong is far too binary to describe that situation. Incomplete is much more appropriate. Do you know what part I'm missing here, as far as rigor is concerned? I'm making an assumption somewhere, right? (My statements are true, just with assumptions, is what I gathered).

Comment: I've written out a complete (although not beautifully structured) proof for you in an answer. One man's "wrong" is another man's "incomplete." For me, part of something being a proof is not just that every statement is true, but that I know why. If only the first condition were necessary, then I could assert that the statement of Fermat's last theorem is also its proof. I doubt anyone would believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0+x) - f(0)}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{g(0+x) - g(0)}
\end{align}
by simple algebra and substitution.

Now the limit of a product is the product of the limits *if both exist*. So to perform the split you wanted, you'll need to show that. The first limit certainly exists, because $f$ is known to be differentiable at 0. What about the second?

Well, if $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = m \ne 0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{h(x)} = \frac{1}{m}$. (This is Theorem 2 of chapter 5 of Spivak's *Calculus*, if you need a reference). We'd like to apply this to the function 
$$
h(x) = \frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}
$$
but to do so, we need to know that $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$ exists and is nonzero.

Fortunately for us, $g$ is differentiable at 0 (by assumption), and its derivative, $g'(0)$, is exactly defined to be $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$, which therefore exists. Furthermore, the hypothesis $g'(0) \ne 0$ tells us that it's nonzero. So we can conclude that

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}} &= \frac{1}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}}\\
&= \frac{1}{g'(0)}. 
\end{align}
Finally, the limit on the left is, through a little algebra, just 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{g(0+x) - g(0)}.
\end{align}

So both the limits in the product into which we want to split our original expression exist and hence we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0+x) - f(0)}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{g(0+x) - g(0)} \\
 &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0+x) - f(0)}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(0+x) - g(0)}{x}} \\
& = f'(0) \cdot \frac{1}{g'(0)} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}
\end{align}